# asp gridview header text justify

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What I need: TARGET or ACTUAL on first line and rest on next line.

[image]

What I have till now

[image]

I have this gridview templatefield in asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle" HeaderText="TARGET Approval Date" FooterStyle-CssClass="alternateStyler" ItemStyle-CssClass="alternateStyler" ItemStyle-Width="8%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="dtTgtApprDate" CssClass="Datetext" Width="98%" Height="23px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Phase2")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="dtTgtApprDate2" CssClass="Datetext" Width="98%" Height="23px" runat="server">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle" HeaderText="ACTUAL Approval Date" FooterStyle-CssClass="alternateStyler" ItemStyle-CssClass="alternateStyler" ItemStyle-Width="8%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" FooterStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="dtActApprDate" CssClass="Datetext" Width="98%" Height="23px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Phase3")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="dtActApprDate2" CssClass="Datetext" Width="98%" Height="23px" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have put this css for HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerStyle"

```
.headerStyle {
    text-justify:distribute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the header is HTML also, you can just put a `<br>` in it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TARGET<br>ApprovalDate">
```